# Есть ли баунти на ru.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: предложение, хэшкод, конкурс

Предлагаю включить. Не знаю как правильно перевести bounty, возможно как "приз".

Пристально всматривался, но не увидел призовых вопросов на ru версии SO. Наверное на это есть причины. Может как-то с наследием хэшкода связано?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть такое, переведено как "конкурс". Под вопросом, который был задан не менее 48 часов назад, имеется надпись "начать конкурс". [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/147334/).

Пока что этой возможностью никто не воспользовался.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит проблема только в "жадности" аудитории? Это поправимо.

Comment: @artoodetoo: ru.SO существует около недели. Более старые вопросы импортированы с Хэшкода (который собственно и «превратился» в ru.SO), там был другой механизм награждения.

Comment: @VladD, это вы на хэшкоде такую репу наели? )))

Comment: @artoodetoo: Ага, на нём)

Comment: А сейчас отключили этот механизм? Почему я не могу начать конкурс по своему вопросу? Прошло уже 5 дней

Comment: @e1s Нужно иметь 75 очков: см [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) (пока не переведено).

Comment: @artoodetoo: на самом деле, вся репа была пересчитана по правилам StackExchange, так что можно сказать, что VladD наел её уже на StackOverflow, но задним числом )

Comment: Не воспользовался? Вот конкурсные вопросы: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured